# passport-azure-ad: Why am I getting "jwt audience is invalid"?

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, adal, passport-azure-ad

(All IDs in the below example are made up. I've added them to illustrate the format for some of the parameters).

My tenant is at acme.co.uk, but I want the web app that I've got deployed at https://subdomain.acme2.co.uk to delegate authentication of users to Azure AD.

I registered my app as below using the [new portal](https://portal.azure.com):
(The field names are those used on the azure portal).

App ID URL: https://acme.co.uk/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555

Home page URL: https://subdomain.acme2.co.uk/api/auth/aad

Reply URLs: https://subdomain.acme2.co.uk/api/auth/aad/callback

and created a secret key that doesn't expire with the value: '111111111111111111/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa='

I've been following the passport-azure-ad github [sample using v1 endpoint](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS) as a guide.

```
{
  allowHttpForRedirectUrl: false,
  clientID: 'https://acme.co.uk/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555',
  clientSecret: '111111111111111111/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=',
  identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/acme.co.uk/.well-known/openid-configuration',
  isB2C: false,
  issuer: null,
  loggingLevel: 'info',
  passReqToCallback: false,
  redirectUrl: 'https://subdomain.acme2.co.uk/api/auth/aad/callback',
  responseMode: 'form_post',
  responseType: 'code id_token',
  skipUserProfile: true,
  useCookieInsteadOfSession: false,
  validateIssuer: true
}
```

When I got to 'https://subdomain.acme2.co.uk/api/auth/aad' in my browser I get redirected to MS to login, which I then do, but when the redirect back to 'https://subdomain.acme2.co.uk/api/auth/aad/callback' happens, I'm not authenticated.

Inspecting the headers from the callback POST request I see:

```
In _validateResponse: jwt audience is invalid. expected: https://acme.co.uk/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555,spn:https://acme.co.uk/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong??? [:-|

(Aside: Debugging this is a pain, as I'm running in docker and the redirects don't seem to work properly, so I have to deploy to a real environment ATM).

Comment: this one https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad/issues/309 ? As a side note, redirects are just regular 302. If you can access the dockerized app in the browser, redirects should work.

Comment: In terms of debugging, I'd suggest to use something like chrome development tool, network tab, enable "preserve log" and compare `state` query string parameter sent to login.microsoftonline.com and the one sent back to `https://subdomain.acme2.co.uk/api/auth/aad/callback`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yeah, I saw that issue but unfortunately I'm one the latest version (3.0.8). I compared the query string state value to the response 'form data'-> 'state' and they were exactly the same (and no URL encoding to be seen).

Comment: Ah... ...redeployed and I get a different error now(?!). In _validateResponse: jwt audience is invalid. expected: https://acme.co.uk/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555,spn:https://acme.co.uk/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 . Any ideas? (Updated the question)

Comment: `aud` part of jwt token returned from azure doesn't match clientID. Check what token you get. Something must be misconfigured.

Comment: ok... so the audience is set to the Application Id of the Azure registered App (not the App Id URI). I found this out by pasting the id_token field in the response into jwt.io. That ID seems correct to me, but I don't understand why the aud field is the App Id, and the _validateResponse is comparing to the clientID (App Id URI)??!

Comment: You may want to use id_token rather than access_token. Checkout my answer on this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76873146/10030693

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found it... 
  clientID: 'https://acme.co.uk/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555'
was the culprit.

That should be the app Id NOT the app Id URI. Doh. Many thanks to @Alex Blex for the guidance. This was most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my instance, I was using .env and getting the clientId from there.

I solved this issue by remove the quotes around clientID in my config and .env file.